# How to add locale to Android WebView application so that Intl.NumberFormat could use it?

Tags: javascript, webview, localization

I am developing a JavaScript application that is run both in Chrome browser and in Android application that uses WebView. The following line `Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf(['et', 'et-EE', 'en'])` yields different results:

- Chrome browser: `["et", "et-EE", "en"]`
- Android application using WebView: `["en"]`

So `Intl.NumberFormat` does not know about "et" (Estonian) locale. How can I fix it?